# Memcache connect throws error in cron job

Tags: php, memcached

When i try to connect to memcached server from a php page, it works without any problem.
Using this code

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

But when it tries to connect to server from a php script which is fired by cron job it throws this error

```
Warning: Memcache::connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/...../cron/acts_cron.php on line 3

Warning: Memcache::connect(): Can't connect to localhost:11211, php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0) in /home/...../cron/acts_cron.php on line 3
Could not connect
```

What can cause this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're missing an entry for localhost inside your hosts file. Try updating /etc/hosts and make sure that you got a line like the following in there:

```
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
```

Comment: i already got this line in hosts file "127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4"

Comment: Is the same server where you execute the page and the cron script?

Comment: Just to rule it out, try connecting to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: But, if you write "nslookup localhost" in your shell you get the correct answer?
Even you can replace "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" in your php code.
Or probably your server is not connected with the loopback network interface. Try ifconfig and watch that "lo" interface is configured

Comment: @Curlas yes after i did "nslookup localhost" i saw that localhost is referring to a wrong IP address. how can i fix this ?

Comment: Probably you have another entry for localhost in the /etc/hosts file? localhost must be present only for 127.0.0.1 But, it's very unusuall, any one put that entry for that ip? and why? Try using "127.0.0.1" right on your php code.

Comment: using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost fixed the issue